# PHP - Anti mitm attack idea

Tags: php, security, man-in-the-middle

I've got an idea against mitm(man-in-the-middle) attacks that i'd like to implement to my site, so i decided to ask you how secure this is. First i'd get 10 page loading times from the client computer in seconds. Then i'd calculate the standard with all those loading times. Then each time the user loads a new page i check if his/her ip address has changed and if it has i recalculate that standard and compare it to the previous standard. If this standard is 1 or 2 bigger that doesn't really matter, but if it's 4 i can log out the user. Then if the attacker has a slower internet connection he would get logged out. I'm sure i'm not the only one who has thought of this, but i don't know if this is used.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Comment: Why not just use established security best practices (TLS) which already mitigate this better?

Comment: This could be like an addon, the cherry on top of the cake

Comment: Wait... "check if his/her ip address has changed and if it has " ... that's not even how a MITM attack works. If the IP changes, why not just always force a login?

Comment: What if the ISP is just having issues the user is on? Also, doesn't sound like  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack the "man" would be present for all 10 requests you built your baseline off.

Comment: You should go ask this question on [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com). No seriously I want to see their reaction. It'll be great, trust me.

Comment: I know this is one of my 5minute ideas XD

Comment: Short answer: it's a bad one, chuck it in the bin. Long answer: Use SSL. Done.

Comment: Yeah, but internet speed analysis at login could maybe help detect something i'll still give this more thought. I'm not going to rely on this, don't worry.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of reasons why this is a bad idea, but:

1. The solution for Man-in-the-Middle attacks are [authenticated encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly) (i.e. TLS 1.1+). **TLS works; USE IT!** You don't even need to do anything clever to use it. Just install [Caddy Server](https://caddyserver.com) if you can't figure out the Apache/nginx/lighttpd configuration and/or LetsEncrypt integration process.
2. MitM attacks, such as those performed by sslstrip, will be indistinguishable from regular users because you'll only see the middleman, not the end user. Aside from that, MitM proxies add microseconds of overhead, which is virtually indistinguishable from network jitter.

are the biggest two.

Answer (score 2):

### Part 1: It doesn't work

Even if your idea worked as you intend it do and describe above, it has issues:

If used standalone, it doesn't protect against passive man-in-the-middle attacks, so an attacker would still be able to steal cookies, passwords, credit cards etc.

If the intention is to use it in addition to TLS, the question becomes: why? If TLS is sufficient this is not needed, and TLS is rather good.

But let's assume for the sake of argument that TLS gets broken. If the attack against TLS is passive, then we're back to the first scenario - no protection against a passive attacker. If the attack against TLS is active, there is still no meaningful protection: Your server will reject the request, but by then it's **too late**. The attacker has already seen the request - and the cookie / password / credit card that was in it!

### Part 2: High false positive rate

Lots of users change IP addresses and lots of users have very variable latencies. You'll be logging them off all the time, which will be a terrible experience for them. I imagine this would affect mobile users in particular.

### Part 3: The usual essay about not inventing your own security mechanisms

TLS is the result of a lot of hard work over a long period of time by a large number of smart people: I mean no insult to you when I say you are unlikely to come up with something better on your own.

Innovations in security typically come from people already familiar with the body of work who make improvements on top of what has come before. Here's why:

Modern security is the result of lots of people making a lot of mistakes over a long period of time and documenting those mistakes in order to learn from them and avoid repeating them. If you want to create your own security mechanisms, you will have to make a very large number of mistakes (mistakes that are well documented and all attackers know about!) before you catch up.

Comment: Maybe there should be A community dedicated to improving small ideas like these and making solid security concepts of them. But you're right.